# How can I use files/directories in python on Linux that start with .?

Tags: python, linux, directory

I'm a COMPLETE beginner to python, I'm making my first python script that really does anything. I'm assigning a directory to a variable so I can use it to move a file, but the directory includes a folder starting with . and python says it's invalid syntax. So how can I get python to ignore the .?
EDIT: Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
Optifine = find /home/Sol33t303/.minecraft -name 
OptiFine_1.10.2_HD_U_E3.jar
shutil.move(Optifine, "/home/Sol33t303/.minecraft/mods")
```

Comment: Please post your code so far. This makes it much easier for us to help.

Comment: Done @ErikCederstrand

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two very different things.

Are you writing **Python** or **Bash**, cause this is totally Bash:

```
Optifine = find /home/Sol33t303/.minecraft -name
```

You can't just run Bash commands inside a Python script!

If, for example you want to run a shell command inside your script and get its output you can use:

```
Optifine = subprocess.check_output(['find', '/home/Sol33t303/.minecraft', '-name'])
```

And then you split the output by line, and foreach line (file found), move it to the desired destination:

```
for line in Optifine.splitlines():
  shutil.move(Optifine, "/home/Sol33t303/.minecraft/mods")
```

Comment: I was reading on how to find files in python and here https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/recursively-finding-files-in-python-using-the-find-command/ it said you can use the find command in python. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Sol33t303, if you would have paid attention to the guide, the first line shows how to do it easily using shell, where as it later goes on to explain how it can be combined with the `subprocess.Popen()`. I presented the even simpler `subprocess.check_output()` alternative.

Comment: In the guide it said "Combined with the subprocess module in Python, it’s easy to use this search capability within a Python script" which I interpreted it as that you didn't NEED to do it but was recommended. Which in hindsight was kind of dumb of me.

Comment: @Sol33t303, the important thing is that now you understand how to combine these two :)